# How does the following mouse rollover work?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm playing around with a web site at the following address

http://jsfiddle.net/deltanovember/h63Vx/3/

The code for the submit button is as follows

```
<input class="ka-form-submit" type="submit" name="contact" value="Submit" />
```

What I don't understand is how the rollover effect is achieved. In "old school" development this would have been done with `onMouseOver` or similar.  However I don't see the button linked to any JavaScript at all.  I know that JavaScript is involved because when I remove the script files, the rollover stops working.  I just can't find the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look under the hood with Firebug revealed that the opacity of the button is changed when the user mouses over the button:

```
opacity: 1;
```

is smoothly changed to:

```
opacity: .7;
```

Look at the karma.js file and you'll see this under the section "Button hover":

```
TTjquery(document).ready(function(){
    TTjquery(".ka_button, #ka-submit, #searchform #searchsubmit, .ka-form-submit, #mc_signup #mc_signup_submit, .fade-me")
        .hover(
            function(){
                TTjquery(this)
                    .stop()
                    .animate({opacity:0.7},250)
            }, 
            function(){
                TTjquery(this)
                    .stop()
                    .animate({opacity:1.0},250)
            }
        );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the .js files are capturing events on the page.  When the submission event happens or the onclick or the onmouseover or whatever for that form name or that form element, as defined in the JS file versus on the element itself, then it is triggering some action.  I'll be honest; I didn't read the JS to verify this, but I feel good about the guess.

Answer (score 0):

This page includes a bunch of jQuery plugins. Click "manage resources" to see what's included. A lot of it is minified, so it's a bit of a pain to tell apart. One of them must attach an javascript mouseover animation on the fly. The animation is smoothly reducing the opacity on mouseover to produce the mouseover effect.

Answer (score 0):

Events can be added to dom elements via JavaScript. jQuery simplifies this.

in pure JS, the common methods are:

```
domnode.onmouseover = somefunc;
function somefunc(e) {
   ...
}
```

-and-

```
if (domnode.addEventListener) {
  domnode.addEventListener('mouseover', somefunc, false);
} else {
  domnode.attachEvent('onmouseover', somefunc);
}
```

This is good because it's moved the functionality out of the content, in a manner that is consistent with MVC (HTML is the model, CSS is the view, JS is the controller).

jQuery simplifies this even further by allowing you to simply select the node and attach the event:

```
$(selector).mouseover(somefunc);
```

additionally, jQuery normalizes the event bindings and event object so that you can have a consistent cross-browser experience.